# Terraform resources dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

I have a module that look like this:

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip-azure" {
  name                = "pip-azure"
  resource_group_name = "az-rg"
  location            = "West Europe"
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

resource "aws_customer_gateway" "cw-aws" {
  bgp_asn    = 65000
  ip_address = azurerm_public_ip.pip-azure.ip_address
  type       = "ipsec.1"

  tags = {
    Name = "cw-aws"
  }
}
```

But when I run `terraform apply` I get the following error:

> │ Error: expected ip_address to contain a valid IPv4 address, got:
> │   32:   ip_address = azurerm_public_ip.pip-vpn-azure-aws.ip_address

I have noticed that when I run `terraform apply` twice, it works, because `azurerm_public_ip.pip-vpn-azure-aws.ip_address` is now in the state, but shouldn't be usable like this, am I doing it wrong, and how to fix this.

Comment: The code in the question is different to the code that the error is complaining about.

Comment: yes I didn't want to put 70 lines, and the code in question give the same error.

Comment: It sounds like the provider is responding to the request to create `azurerm_public_ip.pip-azure` with `ip_address` set to the empty string `""`, which `aws_customer_gateway` then rejects. I expect that a second run of `terraform apply` is then working only because it causes Terraform to ask the provider to refresh the IP address object, at which point the IP address isn't `""` anymore.

Comment: If that's true then it seems like you've found a weird bug in the `hashicorp/azurerm` provider. Perhaps the `azurerm_public_ip` is returning too early before the remote API has finished allocating the IP address, causing it to read as empty/unset, but then by the time you run `terraform apply` the second time the IP address has been allocated.

Comment: Based on [part of the provider source code](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/9cfd6318e4c463d5750a092ae18461ad037b70fc/internal/services/network/public_ip_resource.go#L330-L360) I guess this symptom would occur if the Azure API returned a response with `PublicIPAddressPropertiesFormat` unset, because then the `ip_address` attribute would never get set. If that is the cause then unfortunately I don't think there's any recourse other than reporting a bug in the provider and waiting for it to be fixed. 

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `depends_on: [azurerm_public_ip.pip-azure]` so it'll wait before the IP address is ready

Comment: First, the syntax is wrong. Second, it does not make much sense to use `depends_on` since the implicit dependency should take care of that anyway.

Comment: I tried adding `depends_on = [azurerm_public_ip.pip-azure]` but i still get the same error